# Question about a nowhere dense set define in terms of spheres

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that the set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$  can be written as follows:
\begin{align}
A= \bigcup_{i \in I}  S_i 
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
S_i =\{  x \in \mathbb{R}^2:  \|x\|=c_i \} 
\end{align}
for some $c_i>0$.

Now suppose that a set $A$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Can we show that $I$ has at most countable cardinality?

Comment: What happens if $A\subset \mathbb{R}, S_i =\{  x \in \mathbb{R}:  |x|=c_i \}$ and  $A= \bigcup_{i \in I}  S_i ?$ If you solve this case you have an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to assume that, for $i,j\in I$ with $i\neq j$, it must hold that $c_i\neq c_j$.  Otherwise, you can take all $c_i$'s to be equal and get an obvious counterexample.  From now on, I suppose that the $c_i$'s are pairwise distinct.

Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).  For each $i\in I$, we take $c_i$ to be $1+i$.  Note that $I$ is uncountable and $A$ is a compact set (noting that $A$ can be identified as the product of two compact spaces: the Cantor set $I$ and the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$).  Therefore, the closure $\bar{A}$ of $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $A$ itself.  Thus, the interior of $\bar{A}$ is the same as the interior of $A$, and $A$ has empty interior (why?).  That is, $A$ is nowhere dense.